# Internal Server error: using python script with sqlite + mod_wsgi in apache

Tags: python, sqlite, wsgi

This is my code example.

```
import sqlite3

def application(environ, start_response):

 output = "<p> LOG</p>"

 db = sqlite3.connect('/root/example.db')
 db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
 cursor = db.cursor()
 cursor.execute('''SELECT id, message,date FROM table''')
 for row in cursor:
  print('{0} : {1}, {2}'.format(row['id'], row['message'], row['date']))
 db.close()

start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
return output
```

I get Internal Server Error.

How would solve the problem?

Comment: Have you checked apache logs?

Comment: it would be in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: [Thu Apr 02 20:36:16 2015] [error] [client 172.16.1.1]   File "/var/www/html/controller.py", line 7, in application
[Thu Apr 02 20:36:16 2015] [error] [client 172.16.1.1]     db = sqlite3.connect('/root/example.db')
[Thu Apr 02 20:36:16 2015] [error] [client 172.16.1.1] OperationalError: unable to open database file
[Thu Apr 02 20:36:48 2015] [error] [client 172.16.1.1] mod_wsgi (pid=15627, process='', application='example.com|'): Failed to parse WSGI script file '/var/www/html/controller.py'.

Comment: I guess (or better hope) your webserver is not running as root? You have to put the database in a directory where your webserver can read and write, not `/root`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you webserver (hopefully) doesn't run as the `root`-User, placing your database in the `/root` directory will not work.

You habe to put the database in a directory that is writable by your webserver (as it looks to me, that would be `/var/www` for you).

And just to prevent further privilege problems, the database file needs to be readable and writable by the webserver as well. On Ubuntu/Debian systems, this can be done with

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/example.db
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!   But only shows message LOG.  Checking /var/log/html/error_log appear the values.   But I would like that return row values on the web.  Any idea?

Comment: Of course you have to append the rows to the `output` variable that you are returning and not printing them.